# headless watir webdriver tests unable to find firefox

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, firefox, docker, watir-webdriver

I am setting up watir-webdriver tests on gitlab ci ubuntu image using docker. I am installing firefox from mozilla site and then trying to run the tests. However, I keep getting the error that selenium is unable to find firefox

```
No such file or directory - /usr/bin/firefox (ChildProcess::LaunchError)
```

The steps that I followed to install firefox

```
$wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/35.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-35.0.tar.bz2
$tar xjf firefox-35.0.tar.bz2
$cp -r firefox /opt/firefox35
$ln -s /opt/firefox35/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

I tried changing the sym link path to `/usr/bin/firefox` and `/usr/local/firefox`

I also tried setting the path to firefox explicitly in `env.rb`

`Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = '/usr/local/firefox'`
`Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = '../firefox/firefox'`

I am facing the same issue even with the newer versions of firefox.

I also tried installing firefox using the `apt-get` package manager with same result.

Did any one face this issue and was able to resolve it?

Comment: I assume you are able to launch `firefox` manually just fine and that the user you are installing as is the same as the user driving the Watir (or otherwise has permission to execute Firefox)? Also does `which firefox` point to your install?